# Losing session variables while maintaining session id

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, redirect, session-variables

I am losing the session variable while maintaining the session id with the following code.

**index_simplified.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="processLogin_simplified.php" method="post">
            username:
            <input type="text" class="textfield" name="username">
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**processLogin_simplified.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    session_write_close(); // tried with and without this line

    header('Refresh: 0; URL=https://www.domainname.com/foldername/dashboard_simplified.php');
    exit(); // tried with and without this line
?>
```

**dashboard_simplified.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo 'session id:' . session_id();  
    echo '<br><br>username: ' . $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

output shows the session id but nothing for the username session variable.

It is noteworthy that my full code worked until I purchased SSL through my server company and added the redirect code to the htaccess file of the folder with these files. The code used was:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domainname.com/foldername/$1 [R,L]
```

This successfully redirected users who went to the location using http to the same location with https.  I also tried adding in `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` to ensure a redirect was not occurring when the user initially used https, but this had no effect.

Is there a solution in which my session variables persist?

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by my hosting company. Apparently, the "session .save_pth was not set properly in the php.ini file". Not exactly sure what that means but am pleased it is now working. Hope it helps others.